# Matlab: How do i use ANFIS (Fuzzy Logic Toolbox) for prediction

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

New to Matlab, I can see how ANFIS(http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fp715dup12.html) works in Matlab.
You can input population and train it and test it.
I am wondering how to use ANFIS for prediction(in future).
Is there a way to build a ANFIS model to your specifications/rules or anyway i could get it to generate an equation. 
In other words whats happens after you train and test it? and are happy with the margin of error.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that the "testing" phase is like predicting on a held out set (a future, unseen set). So to use ANFIS for prediction in the future, you would follow the same set of steps given for testing. If this doesn't quite get at what you're looking for, can you clarify with some information about your data and the prediction task you'd like to do?